# Arduino leonardo. Encoder mouse movement

Tags: sensors, arduino-leonardo, rotary-encoder

I want to connect my sensonrs to an arduino leonardo.

The principal idea is use it like a scratch (like dj hero or beatmania??), if I move the scratsh up, the mouse will go up ( y Axis ), and if it go down, the y Axis down.

The middle is for gnd and the other four to 0 to 3 pin in the arduino.

So my problem is I am not sure about the conecction and also the code to run my program, beacuse all the thing that i try to do, had no work in my computer.

[image: Board]

[image: Sensors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a quadrature encoder implemented using photo interrupters. Use a DMM to suss out which half of each is the diode and which is the phototransistor, connect both halves as you would were they independent, and decode the quadrature output.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I did not know the name. I searched and found the map to connect to my arduino.